# Angular 13, Валидация не меняется в зависимости от переключателя

Tags: javascript, angular4

вопрос, у меня есть радиобаттон и в зависимости от его значения, мне нужно делать один из текстареа обязательным или нет, написал код, но что то не работает

```js
this.dataForm.get('hasAccessRoads')?.valueChanges.subscribe({next:(newValue:any)=>{
    console.log('newValue',newValue);
    if(newValue===true) {
      this.dataForm.controls['comment']?.setValidators([]);
    }
    else {
      this.dataForm.controls['comment']?.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
      this.dataForm?.controls['comment']?.updateValueAndValidity();
    }})
```

В чем мб проблема?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139802/discussion-on-question-by-timonrc-angular-13-----).

Answer (score 0):

Так как в данном случае true приходит, не булево, а string, то обернуть if(newValue==="true")

Answer (score 0):

Если критично, чтобы работал именно приложенный код, то следует обратить внимание на [ответ Timonrc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1456249/286191). Если же вы хотите последовать более правильному решению, то для такого случая следует написать декоратор, appRequired, который будет по изменению значения радиобаттона навешивать валидатор.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appRequired]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: AppRequiredValidatorDirective,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class AppRequiredValidatorDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {

    private _required = true;

    @Input('appRequired')
    set required(value: boolean | '') {
        this._required = value === '' || !!value;
    }

    private _onChange: () => void;
    
    public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return this._required
            ? Validators.required()(control)
            : null;
    }
    
    registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
        this._onChange = fn; 
    }

    ngOnChanges(_: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (this._onChange) {
            this._onChange();
        }
    }  
}
```

Пользоваться данным валидатором следующим образом:

```
<textarea formControlName="textarea" [appRequired]="!!form.controls.radiobutton.value"></textarea>
```

Что будет происходить далее:

- Директива, накинутая на элемент, будет отслеживать состояние контрола radiobutton
- Когда значение изменится, директива будет запускать метод validate, который будет проверять контрол на наличие значения

Надеюсь ничего не забыл